# How to set default entry in GRUB2 on EFI with FEDORA 20

Tags: linux, windows-8, boot, fedora, grub

I have Windows 8 dual booting with Fedora 20. Linux is the first one Windows is the third. I want windows to be the default. I am using instructions from [GRUB 2](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2).

```
grep "submenu\|^\menuentry" /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg | cut -d "'" -f2
```

gives

```
Fedora, with Linux 3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64
Fedora, with Linux 0-rescue-62ce70aff0cf43989df5b1dfd30caf79
Windows Boot Manager
```

when I set the default entry by not recommended way:

```
set default="2"
```

Windows becomes default entry. But recommended way

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
grub2-set-default "Windows Boot Manager"
grub2-editenv list
```

gives

```
saved_entry=Windows Boot Manager
```

but after

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
```

The default entry is again Linux.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="Windows Boot Manager"
```

in `/etc/default/grub` and it works.